# How to allow to slide rectangle to not colliding with corners between two rectagles?

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, collision-resolution

I am detecting each side of collision between two rectangles, and wen I collide them, lets say, with the left side, it also detects collision on the top side when I move to the top, and the downside when I move to the bottom. I think that is because it is detecting also the top/bottom corners.

[image]

How I can prevent this corner collision to allow to the player to slide?

Currently, my code is the next one (using xMove (-1 or 1) and yMove (-1 or 1) to know the player movement direction.

```
    if (collider.intersects(mapCollider)) {

            if (direction == Direction.WEST || direction == Direction.EAST) {
                // Right collision
                if (collider.x + collider.width >= mapCollider.x) {
                    isCollisionRight = true;
                }
                // Left collision
                else if (collider.x <= mapCollider.x + mapCollider.width) {
                    isCollisionLeft = true;
                }                   
            }

            if (direction == Direction.NORTH || direction == Direction.SOUTH) {
                // Top collision
                if (collider.y + collider.height >= mapCollider.y) {
                    isCollisionTop = true;
                }
                // Bottom collision
                else if (collider.y <= mapCollider.y + mapCollider.height) {
                    isCollisionBottom = true;
                }
            }
```

Best regards,
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests for top/bottom collision are only false if `mapCollider.y == playerCollider.y`, i.e. if their tops are exactly aligned. However, this doesn't indicate whether a collision is occurring in that direction, you need to be testing for the edges of your bounding boxes, not just a single point.

For example, for left/right collision, this should be something like:

```
// Right collision
if (
    (playerCollider.x + playerCollider.width) >= mapCollider.x 
    && (playerCollider.x + playerCollider.width) <= (mapCollider.x + mapCollider.width))
{
    isCollisionRight = true;
}

// Left collision
if (
    playerCollider.x <= (mapCollider.x + mapCollider.width)
    && playerCollider.x >= mapCollider.x )
{
    isCollisionLeft = true;
}
```

Note that only one of left/right collision should be true at a time, unless the player completely inside the object.

Also, some version of this is very likely what the `intersect` function you are calling is doing, is there a version that returns the intersection you can call? Or otherwise you might want to replace it with your own code.

Comment: Hi Jack, I edited the question for you to know where x and y coords are positioned on the rectangles, because the (0, 0) coords are not in the centers, they are in the top left corners.

Comment: @Asier: That doesn't actually affect the substance of the problem, you're still comparing a single point in the object when you need to be comparing edges.

Comment: Hi Jack, ok I undertand, I need also check with the sum of the x + width of the rectangles to check the side collisions, but i tried (playerCollider.x + playerCollider.width) > mapCollider.x for the right position, and it is detecting me all sides with right :/

Comment: @Asier: The `.intersects()` call is supposed to filter out non-intersections. What is `belongsToLevel.tiledMap.mergedColliders`? How is it calculated? Also by "right collision" do you mean the object or the player is on the right?

Comment: Hi Jack, the mergedColliders are the map colliders (in this case the castle), and is calculated getting the rectangle that I created in Tiled, wich has a specific coordinates in the map. About the side collisions, when I say top/right/left/bottom I am refering to the player, because I want to detect the side of the player rect.

Comment: Hi again Jack, I edited my question changing the code to more apropiate one, and I understand the side checking logic. My only problem now is that when the right side or the top side, I am doing >=, and this causes true in all cases, not allowing to check the next else if for the other side :(

Comment: @Asier: Hmm, yes, you're correct you will need to do the full collision comparison for both sides. I have updated the answer.